# Raspberry Pi as bluetooth Microphone

Tags: audio, bluetooth

I would like to use the raspberry pi as a bluetooth microphone for my iphone. Not the speaker, ONLY the microphone. My vision is to have a microphone plugged into the raspberry pi that could connect using bluetooth to my phone. I do this because I need a way to connect my phone to a microphone without using the headphone jack (more details [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/333103/use-wired-microphone-without-headphones-on-iphone)). Is this possible? I don't want to have to buy a bluetooth microphone if it is not necessary.